# Finding partial text match using any in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of string that contains values like this:

- 'abc_def'
- '{xyz_abc}'
- '{www-ABC-zzz}'

I wish to find partial text match in my list using the `any` keyword:

```
result = any('abc' in w for w in list)
```

How can I find all the matching while ignoring upper case of lower case and yet find partial text match?

Comment: "**all** the matching" and `any` are about different things

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest So I can find all, not any?

Comment: What exactly do you want to be the output?

Comment: True if item in my list contain ABC or abc, False otherwise

Comment: If that's what you want, then I would just add a lower() call so that the case is forced to lower: `result = any("abc" in w.lower() for w in list1)`

Comment: @TalAngel, `res = ["abc" in w.lower() for w in lst]`

Comment: Obviously for more advanced substring matching, you could use regular expressions as well, but that will return the actual matches rather than just a boolean. That said, you could easily write a function that evaluates the expression and then returns a boolean result depending on the output.

Comment: Are you trying to find the matching strings or if there are any matches?

Comment: @TalAngel if you could edit the question to be more specific on the output you're seeking (ie do you want a single boolean output? Or a list of booleans representing each element in the input list? or do you want the actual string matches as others have asked, etc) that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```py
r = [w for w in list if 'abc' in w.lower()]
```

if you want to return the list of matched string

```py
r = [if 'abc' in w.lower() for w in list ]
```

or a list of booleans.

Regular expression (see package re from the standard) or unix pattern matching (see package fnmatch) might be required for more sophisticated cases